# Footer not responding in PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, preference

I've tried to add my footer in my preference screen, but my buttons in it are not responding. Also, when I call the EditTextPreference, my footer moves too.. Any idea?

Here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your layout like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <include
            android:id="@+id/your_footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            layout="@layout/footer" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/your_footer">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```